# Hide item from list on click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and Typescript and have difficulties figuring out **how to hide a ticket from the list when I press on hide**.

```
renderTickets = (tickets: Ticket[]) => {
  const filteredTickets = tickets.filter(t =>
    (t.title.toLowerCase() + t.content.toLowerCase() + t.visible).includes(
      this.state.search.toLowerCase()
    )
  );

  return (
    <ul className="tickets">
      {filteredTickets.map(ticket => (
        <li key={ticket.id} className="ticket">
          <a className="hide-btn" onClick={() => (ticket.visible = false)}>
            Hide
          </a>
          <h5 className="title">{ticket.title}</h5>
          <p className="content">{ticket.content}</p>
          <footer>
            <div className="meta-data">
              By {ticket.userEmail} |{" "}
              {new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()}
            </div>
          </footer>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

```
export type Ticket = {
    id: string,
    title: string;
    content: string;
    creationTime: number;
    userEmail: string;
    labels?: string[];
    visible: boolean;
}
```

Comment: use state to handle your ticket visibility.

Comment: I've tried but I don't really know how to do it with types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like demkovych said, you're going to want to use state here. I suggest extracting the rendering of an individual ticket into a new React class like so (I'm not using react hooks here):

```
interface TicketListItemProps {
    ticket: Ticket;
}

interface TicketListItemState {
    isVisible: boolean;
}

class TicketListItem extends React.Component<TicketListItemProps, TicketListItemState> {
    state: TicketListItemState = {
        isVisible: false
    };

    onClick = () => this.setState({ isVisible: true });

    public render() {
        const { ticket } = this.props;

        if (!this.state.isVisible) return null;

        return <li key={ticket.id} className='ticket'>
            <a className='hide-btn' onClick={this.onClick}>Hide</a>
            <h5 className='title'>{ticket.title}</h5>
            <p className='content'>{ticket.content}</p>
            <footer>
                <div className='meta-data'>By {ticket.userEmail} | { new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()}</div>
            </footer>
        </li>
    }
}
```

This way, the visibility of ticket list item is bound to the child component, instead of the parent component.